# How to bind mouse buttons to keys?

Tags: mouse, scripts, input-devices

I have a *Logitech MX400 Laser Mouse* which has 5 buttons + 4 for vertical/horizontal scrolling. I would like it set up so instead of horizontal scrolling pressing right on the scrollwheel will send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and left will send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, which will allow me to cycle through tabs in browsers.

Also, it would be nice if I could remap the middle button to one of the ones on the side as it is really hard to press down.

Another bonus would be if I could write a script that allows me to define what buttons do what dependent on which window is currently active.

I have tried using `xmodmap` but I could only see how to rearrange buttons, not have them send key signals.

Thanks in advance.

---

Button Map (using `xev`):

```
Left        1
Middle      2
Right       3
ScrollUp    4
ScrollDown  5
ScrollLeft  6
ScrollRight 7
Backward    8
Forward     9
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) and [xte](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) can help you.

For example my .xbindkeysrc file looks like this:

```
# close the window under the mouse cursor
"xte 'mouseclick 1' && xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key F4' 'keyup Alt_L'"
  b:8+Release

# double click
"xte 'mouseclick 1' 'mouseclick 1'"
  b:9
```

Comment: This is fantastic and extensible, many many thanks

Comment: To get **xte** on Ubuntu 16.x, you'll have to install **xautomation** from _apt_.

Comment: That doesn't work as well as I like, because it doesn't work the same if I hold the button down.

My old mouse had a button that enables the scroll wheel to spin freely, which is great if I just want to start it moving real fast and scroll a long way. But my new one doesn't have that, so I bound two buttons on the side (I think they're designed as back/forward buttons for Web browsing) to the PgUp/PgDn keys. But I have to press them repeatedly if I want to keep scrolling; I can't just hold them down. How do I make it hold the key as long as I hold the button?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to everyone for the solution. Here is a more foolproof/combined guide (done on Xubuntu 18.04).

1. Open a terminal (like xterm/terminal/terminator), become root (`sudo su -`) or use sudo in front of the command:

   ```
   apt install xbindkeys xautomation
   ```
2. Check the button mapping with `xev`, for this you don't need root permission so exit the root session (with `exit`) or open another terminal as user.

   ```
   xev | grep button
   ```
3. A small window will appear. You have to move the mouse into that window and press the button you want to remap. An example output in the terminal will be:

   ```
   state 0x0, button 8, same_screen YES
   ```

   This is the 2nd side button on my mouse which I want to use as PAGE_DOWN.

   ```
   state 0x0, button 9, same_screen YES
   ```

   This is the 1st (yes, the order is reversed) side button I want to use as PAGE_UP.
4. When you have all buttons you want to remap you can close the small xev window. Open your favorite editor (gedit/vi/nano for example) and edit the configuration file.

   ```
   vi .xbindkeysrc
   ```
5. If you already have some content in the file, look if there is already a binding like it (unlikely, not by default) and add at the end.

   ```
   #Pagedown press
   "xte 'keydown Next'"
   b:8

   #Pagedown release
   "xte 'keyup Next'"
   b:8 + Release

   #Pagedup press
   "xte 'keydown Prior'"
   b:9

   #Pageup release
   "xte 'keyup Prior'"
   b:9 + Release
   ```

   Note: you need two entries, one for the button press and one for the release.
6. The buttons 8+9 will be mapped to the keys "Next" (which is PAGE_DOWN) and "Prior" (PAGE_UP). If you want to map different keys you can find the keysymbol with xev.

   ```
   xev | grep keysym
   ```
7. Like before, start it in a terminal, move the mouse to the small window and press the wanted key.

   ```
   state 0x0, keycode 117 (keysym 0xff56, Next), same_screen YES,
   ```
8. Save and kill xbindings.

   ```
   killall xbindkeys ; xbindkeys
   ```

You can now use the additional side buttons on the mouse. The setting will be loaded automatically on next reboot/login. You only need the `killall [...]` command from above if you change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me, and my Logitech G402 mouse, the Piper mouse configuration tool worked perfectly!

https://github.com/libratbag/piper

installable via apt

```
sudo apt install piper
```