# Left mouse button stops working

Tags: 10.10, hardware, mouse

The left mouse button stops working after 5 or 10 minutes of running Ubuntu 10.10.
It is a Logitech MX 1000 wireless USB mouse.
Also is there a way to emulate the left mouse click on the keyboard?
Mouse pointer move fine, right button works, wheel works.

Comment: Here's [How to bind mouse buttons to keys](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9048/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keys).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.  Here's how to solve it. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:raof/aubergine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

...and when the update/upgrade is complete, reboot your system and VOILA! The mouse (including left-click) works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  In the end, I tried another mouse, and it worked - decided it was a hardware issue... mice do break!