# Binding Mouse Movement To Keyboard Keys

Tags: keyboard, mouse, games

I have a little Blue Gaming Mouse (Don't remember the name) and I've been searching everywhere to find an answer, so here it is.
I would like to bind Mouse movement to Keyboard keys. I would like to bind the Mouse Movement to the right to the D key and Left, A key. I would appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/9064/428191) in the past and can confirm that it sufficiently answers your question

Comment: Does this let me make my mousemovent press keys.
So I want my A to be pressed when I look left etc.